# How to design an appropriate Firebase/NoSQL data structure

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase and working with NoSQL database structures. I am trying to achieve an end goal of a  Weight Lifting Tracker iOS application.

The application will hold different users who will each record their own workouts and then should be able to view a history of the workouts they have performed along with the weights they have lifted so progress can be monitored.

The database will hold a list of pre defined exercises with the ability to add unique exercises so that it is only available for that user as well as the predefined list.

The user will be able to define a routine which is created by storing a name, date created, exercises in that workout, and a default timer for rest between exercises.

The user will then perform a workout routine where by they will actually select the routine created above and track what weights they have lifted and for how many sets, e.g.

```
Bench Press:
Set 1: 80kg x 8 reps
Set 2: 80kg x 8 reps
Set 3: 80kg x 6 reps
...
```

However the user may not always create a routine before starting a workout so they will be choosing exercises from the list of pre-defined exercises.

I have the following structure for my NoSQL database and wanted to know if what I have done is correct, this is the first time I have tried to design a model for the problem so any suggestions are welcome to help improve and a possible explanation so I can go away and improve the overall design:

```
{
  "users": {
    "user unique identifier": {
      "name": "User Full Name",
      "email": "User Email",
      "profileImageUrl": "Profile Image Url",
      "routines": {
        "routine unique identifier": true
      },
      "workout routine":{
        "workout routine unique identifier": true
      }
    }
  },
  "exercises": {
    "exercise unique identifier": {
      "exercise_name": "exercise name",
      "body_part": "body part",
      "routines": {
        "routine unique identifier": true
      }
    }
  },
  "routines": {
    "routine unique identifier": {
      "routine_name": "routine name",
      "routine_create_date": "routine created date",
      "exercises":{
        "exercise unique identifier": true
      },
      "default timer": "timer duration"
    }
  },
  "workout routine": {
    "workout routine unique identifier": {
      "date": "workout routine start date",
      "start_time": "workout routine start time",
      "end_time": "workout routine end time",
      "duration": "start_time - end_time",
      "end_date": "workout routine end date",
      "routine unique identifier": {
        "exercise unique identifier": {
          "exercise name": "exercise name",
          "set n weight": "weight lifted in set n"
          "set n reps": "Reps performed for set n",
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>Should be an array, not an object</del>

- <del>`users.uid.workoutroutine`</del>
- <del>`exercises.uid.routines`</del>
- <del>`routines.uid.exercieses`</del>

I suggest your `workoutroutine.uid` to have references to the other objects, not make them another object inside.

The reason for this is for you to not have any issues in casting the object, with the current structure, `uid.routineId` will have different keys (which will probably have a casting error.

You can read more about the best practices in Firebase's [Structure Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) documentation

**EDIT**

Apologies for the confusion, I was actually referring to using defined key-pair structure similar to the following pseudo-code

```
{users:
    [userid]:{
        ...
        workoutroutine:[{
            workoutroutineId:XXXX},
            ....
        ]
     }
}
```

This way, the above reasoning will still be valid, while providing you flexibility with avoiding any casting error. And, as @Frank-van-Puffelen said, there's no single correct design and will depend on your app. Think of it as a suggestion to improve it.

Comment: The Firebase documentation is quite explicit about *not* using arrays: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: I was confused by the suggestion of an array not an object, @FrankvanPuffelen could you advise on my above design please?

Comment: There is no single correct design for a NoSQL database. It all depends on how you app wants to use the data. See [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Does the above structure seem feasible for it to work, if not what structure would you recommend? Sorry for asking many questions I really want to understand how I could this to get to work!

Comment: It's a data structure - nothing about it inherently "works" or doesn't. If you have problems making a specific use-case work on this data structure, post the [minimal code that reproduces that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, thanks for the heads up! I was thinking of a different approach than the array answer from the looks of it. I've updated my answer with what I think would fit better.

Comment: Much better. But do remove the array inside `workoutroutine`, which is likely just a force of habit. I'd normally expect `workoutroutines: { workoutRoutineId1: true, workoutRoutineId2: true }`. That's how you model a **set** in Firebase, which is what in my experience most developers are looking for when they use an array.